# Python:converting string to objects

Tags: python, eval

Say I have an file describing a graph in a format like this:

```
Directional:True
Simplicity:True
{
    1:[2,3]
    2:[1,3]
}
```

and I have a graph class defined like below:

```
class Graph:

def __init__(self,directional = False,simple=True,Filename=None):
    self.adjacencyList = {}
    self.directional = directional
    self.simple = simple
    if not Filename:
        _readFile(Filename)
```

Is there anyway to convert this file to this class **easily**. I know I can write a function to read from the file line by line and do the thing myself. But since python is a highly developed language is there any easy way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be able to add commas and brackets in the right places using regex so that you can `ast.literal_eval()` the resulting Python object.

Comment: Doing it yourself line-by-line is quite easy. Use regular expressions and `str.split()` to parse the lines.

Comment: can you be more specific on this? thanks

Comment: Using regular expressions you can break a line such as "2:[3,5,7,8]" into "2", ":[", "3,5,7,8" and "]". Then you can split the string "3,5,7,8" into "3", "5", "7" and "8" using str.split().

Answer (score 0):

No, since the file doesn't adhere to any standard/popular format. It's close to YAML, but not close enough for direct parsing.